# Push id to ElasticSearch via PIG

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to push the _id field via ESStorage / PIG towards the ES cluster? The [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/pig.html) doesn't state anything related to this subject.

Comment: @Ankit, why did you remove the documentation link?

Comment: Its not removed at all. Click on blue coloured documentation and it will redirect you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/jK_MDNyeRgI), this functionality is in the current development version. Example:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE id, name, TOBAG(url, picture) AS links 
STORE B INTO 'pig/update' USING org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.ESStorage('es.mapping.id=id')
```